# c# <code> and <c> doesn't show up in intellisense <summary>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I tried to use `<c>` and `<code>` in `<summary>` but in IntelliSense it only showed up as plain text.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// <c>DoWork</c> <code>int</code> not working
/// <para> <see cref="int"/> a = 10; </para>
/// <c>
/// int a = 10;
/// </c>
/// </summary>
```

Only the `para` line is working, somewhat, because I still couldn't use class or method names. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community.  The text inside the code tags should be different color if it's a type like  is blue, right?

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a screenshot since we can't see what your syntax highlighting is doing from just a code sample.

Comment: @CalumHalpin Updated the question, I basically want the intellisense summary description to look like like the second row, like in visual studio colorized. Not just the int, but class and other words to be recognized and para seems limited in that regard.